# Can't solve mysterious 20 seconds http delay

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, performance, connection, http

I read a few similar questions, but they seem to be always different somehow. The situation here is very puzzling: for a handful of websites, I get a roughly 20 seconds delay when requesting any page

[image: Screenshot showing "Waiting:" 20407 ms]

[image: Screenshot showing 20.8 second wait for webpage to load]

- Exactly the same behavior happens with Chrome, IE, Firefox.
- The same websites are fast from anywhere else. I can make a simultaneous request on my office PC via remote desktop and see the huge difference in real-time.
- Win 8.1 PC, home LAN. Other devices on the LAN (cabled or wifi) don't have the same issue, so I exclude the router.
- Removing Antivirus and stopping any non-essential windows service that I could didn't change anything.

I don't know where to look anymore... I'm currently remoting into my office to deal with these site as otherwise it's a nightmare.

Any ideas?

**2017 UPDATE:** I never found the solution and ended up reinstalling Windows to get rid of it.

Comment: try this https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/106010?hl=en-GB  though it shouldn't cause a 20 second delay.   Another thing you could do is try wireshark see if it gives you any clues

Comment: @barlop It's one of the first things I thought (and checked), but it affects all browsers. Let me see if wireshark reveals anything.

Comment: Just trying to isolate it further - any of the sites public we can look at? Dumb hunch as well, same DNS server for all working and non-working machines?

Comment: @chris last time I checked(over a year ago), firefox had changed to using the same proxy setting as chrome/IE.. so if it were that setting it would affect all browsers

Comment: out of interest, what performance monitoring program have you provided screenshots of there?

Comment: @tanantish - one example is http://www.heavydutytools.org/to/backpain-mattress which is supposed to be a 307 redirection to a page on the same  site, which means there shouldn't be a DNS issue. But let me have a look at the other machines.

Comment: @barlop - right, I just found that out too... but unfortunately they are all clear. As for the screenshots, one is Firefox's dev tools and the other is Chrome's (hit F12).

Comment: Hm, running low on ideas.. was hoping you just had a dev DNS master you were pointing at which was failing resolution (4 objects, 5s stall etc etc). Dumb thing - if you kick the machine into safe mode, do you still get the 20s delay?

Comment: according to your added picture the problem is either caused by css or javascript maybe both together - this can be caused by various things eg. browser plugins - since you said all browsers i suggest you may be using a password Manager which has a browser Plugin on all Browsers can you try it without that plugin enabled?

Comment: Had this same problem today; about 20 second delay.  It was ONLY for HTTP, HTTPS was unaffected.  @chris, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @JonWadsworth, I never found a solution. At the end I had to reinstall Windows to get rid of it.